# What does “six point something” mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

There was the following passage in a newspaper article, which I failed to take note of the source:

> If he (Trump) seems better than expected, either by throwing Clinton
>   off her game or appearing calmer than a wound-up opponent who gives **a
>   dense six-point answer** to every question, he might achieve something
>   similar to Reagan’s ‘There you go again!

Although I guess “six-point answer” means "full marks, a perfect answer," I’m not certain.

According to www.religionacts.com, 'six-points' stands for the six days of creation, and also represents the six attributes of God: power, wisdom, majesty, love, mercy and justice, but I don’t know how it relates to "six-point answer," or anything else.

What does “six-point answer (question, offense, defense, performance, whatever)" mean?

I’m also interested in the use of the adjective, “dense,“ which seems a bit incongruent to the word, answer, to me. Can I say “It’s a dense answer” colloquially in place of a perfect answer?

Comment: In that sense, "six point answer" means an answer with six "bullet points".  (Ie, the answer is not simple, listing only the one or two main points to be considered.)

Comment: And "dense" means very complex and detailed.

Comment: @Hot Licks. What are "six bullet points"? What are "bullet points" on earth? OALED at hand doesn't show  the word, "bullet points," though it shows "bullet proof.

Comment: If you edit your answer, you will see, on the "toolbar" above the edit panel, a button with numbers 1/2/3 on it, for a numbered list, and to the right of that a button with three dots on it, for a "bullet list", where "bullet" is the name used for the dot.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography)

Comment: Can you give a link to the original so we can see the context (also citation for a quote)?

Comment: @YoichiOishi ODO have a whole descriptive section on bullet points and where to use and not use them; [see here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/bullet-points). Imagine someone who compiles a list of multiple bullet points with lots of information every time he's asked a simple question—that's what the quote here expresses.

Comment: ＠Janus Bahs Jacquet. A ha! That is familiar one I used to use in the exhibits to be shown at client presentations when I was working in an ad agency called McCann Erickson. We called it “write in the bullet form.” I was told to summarize the points in “bullet form” by boss. It’s a nostalgic term, but I didn’t realize that “six point answers” means “six bullet-point answers” at all. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

@HotLicks is exactly right. A *dense six-point answer* is an answer that has *six points* or parts, and *dense* refers to the answer comprising six parts (as opposed to one or two parts), to the complexity of one or more of the six parts, or to some combination of the two. A *dense six-point answer* is the opposite of a simple answer, e.g., a yes-or-no answer.

- Point one
- Point two
- Point three
- Point four
- Point five
- Point six

Comment: Is it worth adding/clarifying that "a dense six-point answer" isn't idiomatic in any way, and the number "six" was just selected by the author as a biggish number? The OP certainly suspected that the phrase was idiomatic and meant "full marks / perfect".